compare two blob colomn values to find percentage of similarity
how to compare two blob colomns on the same table ?
For example: PIC1 contains a picture of a bridge taken from 5 meter distance, whereas PIC2 contains a picture of the same bridge taken from 10 meter distance.
I want to compare using query to show that these two colomns have X% similarity. If this X% is not met, then i flag the record as "not X% similar".
is that possible to do it via query ? if not, what kind processing do I need ?

You need to figure out what "similarity" means to you first. Given your example, a simple comparison of image structure "mostly light top-left, mostly dark bottom-middle" might be enough. For something more complex than that you are looking at image analysis/AI stuff. Before any of that you'd need to translate to some common image format of course. None of that is "built-in" to any standard RDBMS I know of. You can of course embed C,Python,Java functions into PostgreSQL and use libraries from those though.

The algorithm falls outside of the scope of the database engine. You'll need to perform that computation in your app.
